# Declarative Authorization - how to set acces for all actions in controller?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, declarative-authorization

I use **Declarative Authorization** gem and in my **authorization_rules.rb** I have following rule:

```
  role :admin do
    has_permission_on :users, :to => [manually set up all actions in this controller]
  end
```

Exist any more elegant way to set up the access for all actions in the respective controller? I tried these ways

> ```
>   role :admin do
>     has_permission_on :users, :to => :all
>   end
>
>   role :admin do
>     has_permission_on :users
>   end
> ```

But nothing works me. Is there any better way to set up all actions in the controller than slavishly type every single action?

Answer (score 0):

Actions are public methods on a controller class.  Code below is untested but should get you started.

```
c = MyController
actions = []
c.public_methods(false).each { |m| actions << m.to_sym }

role :admin do
  has_permission_on :users, :to => actions
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

```
has_permission_on :controller, :to => [:all]
```